Truncation error for probability vectors in high dimensions
Suppose I have a probability vector $\vec{u}$ of large dimension $d$, i.e. all the entries are positive and sum to $1$. I am interested in the setting where I am given that its $\ell_2$ norm is large, e.g. $\|\vec{u}\|_2 \in \Omega(\frac{1}{\text{poly}\log{d}})$.
I would like to characterise the error of approximating $\vec{u}$ by keeping its $T$ most significant entries, $$\|\vec{u} - \vec{u}_T\|_2 \le \epsilon(d,T).$$
Specifically I would like to know what is the worst-case scaling of $\epsilon$ with $T$. Choosing $u_i \propto 1/i$ gives $\epsilon \in \Omega(T^{-1})$, is this the worst possible scaling?
Intuitively the norm condition means the vector is approximately sparse, and a $T$-term approximation should be quite accurate. However the previous counterexample shows that it may not always be. What are conditions such that the approximation error decays exponentially with $T$?

With no assumption, the worst case is $u_i=1/d$ so that $\epsilon=1-T/d$. That's significantly worse than your case where $\epsilon \sim 1-\log(T)/\log(d)$. But of course this case is very much prohibited by your approximate-sparsity condition.

Yes you're right of course. I have now refined the question, now it is specifically for the case where the approximate sparsity condition holds.
